# Which format of compress is suitable for large map output in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, compression, mapreduce

I am new in hadoop and i am working with a program that its map output is very large versus the size of input file.

I installed lzo library and changed the config files, but it didn't have any effect on my program. how do i compress map output? is lzo the best case?

If yes, how do i implement that in my program?

Answer (score 4):

To compress the intermediate output (your map output), you need to set the following properties in your mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
```

If you want to do it on a job per job basis, you could also directly implement that in your code in 1 of the following ways:

```
conf.set("mapred.compress.map.output", "true")
conf.set("mapred.map.output.compression.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec");
```

or

```
jobConf.setMapOutputCompressorClass(LzoCodec.class);
```

Also it's worth mentioning that the property `mapred.output.compression.type` should be left to the default of `RECORD`, because `BLOCK` compression for intermediate output causes bad performance.

When choosing what type of compression to use, I think you need to consider 2 aspects:

- **Compression ratio**: how much compression actually occurs. The higher the %, the better the compression.
- **IO performance**: since compression is an IO intensive operation, different methods of compression have different performance implication.

The goal is to balance compression ratio and IO performance, you can have a compression codec with very high compression ratio but poor IO performance.

It's really hard to tell you which one you should use and which one you should not, it also depends on your data, so you should try a few ones and see what makes more sense. In my experience, Snappy and LZO are the most efficient ones. Recently I heard about LZF which sounds like a good candidate too. I found a post proposing a benchmark of compressions [here](http://blog.erdemagaoglu.com/post/4605524309/lzo-vs-snappy-vs-lzf-vs-zlib-a-comparison-of), but I would definitely advise to not take that for ground truth and do your own benchmark.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't affect my program. do i have to install lzo?

Comment: @Charles sir : +1 for "mapred.output.compression.type"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Hadoop 0.21 or later, you have to set these properties in your mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.output.compress</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec</name>
  <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
```

And do not forget to restart hadoop after the change. Also make sure that you have both 32-bit and 64-bit liblzo2 installed. For detailed help on how to set this you can refer the following links :

https://github.com/toddlipcon/hadoop-lzo

https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/hadoop-gpl-compression/wiki/FAQ?redir=1

And along with the points made by Charles sir, you should keep 1 more aspect in mind :

- **CPU cycles** : The compression algorithm which you are going to use should consume lesser number of CPU cycles. Otherwise, the cost of compression can void or reverse the speed advantage.

Snappy is another option, but it is primarily optimized for `64-bit` machines. If you are on 32-bit machines better be careful.

Based on the recent progress `LZ4` also seems good and has been recently integrated into Hadoop. It's fast but has higher memory requirements. You can go [here](http://fastcompression.blogspot.in/p/lz4.html) to find more on LZ4.

But as Charles sir has said a fair decision can be made only after some experiments.

Comment: what makes you believe LZ4 has higher memory requirements ?

Comment: Fast in-memory compression, IMHO. Specially in the era of multi-core machines.

Comment: As far as I can tell, LZ4 memory requirement is 16KB per thread for compression, and a few bytes for decompression (excluding input/output buffers). This is outside of my definition of "high memory requirement".

Comment: There is a difference between 'high' and 'higher'. By higher in my answer I meant its memory requirements are higher than other compression types I was talking about.

Comment: I only have a 64 bit jdk. Will I need to get a 32 bit jdk as well?